# Gravitational Deflection of light

Tags: general-relativity

I'm looking for an expression for the deflection of light in a static gravitational field. Referring to 'deflection of star light past the sun' in Sean Carroll's "Spacetime and Geometry" - equation 7.80 for the "transverse gradient":

$$
\nabla\perp\Phi = \frac{GM}{(b^2 + x^2)^{3/2}}\vec b
$$
Deflection angle is 
$$
\alpha =  {2GMb} \int ​​{\frac{dx}{(b^2 + x^2)^{3/2}}} = \frac{4GM}{b}
$$
As far as I understand it, this transverse gradient is only valid for weak fields/small deflection. And I'm not looking for a general integral solution - I'd like to plot photon paths in strong fields, so I'm looking for the instantaneous deflection, which I'll plot/integrate numerically, based on mass, radial distance from mass, and initial angle of photon trajectory. It should not use the Schwarzschild solution/metric, because I don't want the singularity at r=Rs and it only needs to be in 2 dimensions, because of spherical symmetry. So, is there an expression for the polar coordinates r2, θ2 and trajectory a2, for a photon travelling from p1 to p2, using M, r1, θ1, a1, L? Below is a diagram which I hope illustrates it.

[image: Deflected Photon Path]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand if you want a "general solution" you have to integrate to obtain the solutions for a null geodesic. That cannot be done in general and each static gravitational field will produce a different answer.